# How to add data parameter in ajaxSend properly?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-1.4

In some circumstance I need to add POST parameter programmatically to AJAX request.

I'm trying something like this:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions) {
    ajaxOptions.data = "additional_key=additional_value&" + ajaxOptions.data;
    ajaxOptions.context.data = "additional_key=additional_value&" + ajaxOptions.context.data;
    console.log(ajaxOptions, 'ajaxOptions');
});
```

But additional_key isn't appear in $_POST array.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `ajaxPrefilter` for this :

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    if (originalOptions.type !== 'POST' || options.type !== 'POST') {
        return;
    }

    options.data = $.extend(originalOptions.data, { yourdata : yourvalue });
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxprefilter/ for more infos.

Comment: thanks but I need use jQuery 1.4.4. Using Drupal 7 and newer versions of jQuery causes problems on this platform

Comment: ajaxPrefilter added on jQuery version 1.5.

Comment: You did not mention the jQuery version btw.

Comment: Upvoted this answer because even this won't fit OP needs (jq 1.4.4), this will be useful for futur readers, i guess...

Answer (score 2):

testing your above code gave me an error that `ajaxOptions.context` was undefined.

First, I'd advise that you check for existence first: (Assuming that context is ever going to be defined)

```
if(ajaxOptions.context) {
    ajaxOptions.context.data = "additional_key=additional_value&" + ajaxOptions.context.data;
} else {
    ajaxOptions.data = "additional_key=additional_value&" + ajaxOptions.data;
}
```

Sending off a mock AJAX request showed me that the data is being passed through when inspected in Firebug.

I tested the code by removing the context line, and it seemed to work:

Code:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions) {
    if(ajaxOptions.context) {
        ajaxOptions.context.data = "additional_key=additional_value&" + ajaxOptions.context.data;
    } else {
        ajaxOptions.data = "additional_key=additional_value&" + ajaxOptions.data;
    }
});

$.ajax({
    'url': 'test.php',
    'data': {'foo':'bar'},
    'type': 'POST'
});
```

Inspection:

```
Key             Value
additional_key  additional_value
foo             bar
```

Edit: Tested with JQuery 1.7.1 I've noticed that you're running a lower version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).ajaxSend(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions) {
        if (ajaxOptions.extraData) {
            ajaxOptions.extraData.additional_key = 'additional_value';
        }
    });
});
```

This only work for me (jQuery 1.4.4)